# javascript syntax : <div class="<c:if> "

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp

I am trying to hide a certain form when a certain value from a different dropdown box from the page is selected.

I have a dropdown box defined in jsp like:

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
   <select id="gasGrade">
      <option value="0" label="unleaded"></option>
      <option value="1" label="premium"></option>
      <option value="2" label="super premium"></option>
   </select>
</div>
```

On the page, whenever user selected option value 2 (super-premium) from that box, I want some buttons to disappear.

I want this form to disappear:

```
<div class="form-group col-lg-4 <c:if test="$('#gasGrade').val()=='2'"> hidden </c:if>" id="pay">
   <div class="col-lg-4">
      <input type="radio" name="pay" value="0">visa<br>
      <input type="radio" name="pay" value="1">amex<br>
      <input type="radio" name="pay" value="2">cash
   </div>
</div>
```

However, this snippet of code inside the div class is not working:

```
<c:if test="$('#gasGrade').val()=='2'"> hidden </c:if>"
```

Furthermore, I've tried

```
<c:if test="${gasGrade} == '2'"> hidden </c:if>"
```

And several other variations of this. What is the correct syntax to use the value from another input field on same page to hide a form?

Comment: doesn't the jsp run and finish before the user can click anything?

Comment: is this way not plausible then if that is the case?

Comment: Your `test` clause looks like JavaScript, not JSTL/EL syntax, so it does not make any sense. The JSTL stuff is evaluated on the **server**, not the client, so JavaScript is irrelevant.

Comment: apologize, my mistake, misuse of words, does it make sense if i dismiss the fact i mentioned jstl?

Comment: use a simple classname combo, like `<select id="gasGrade" onchange='document.body.dataset.mode=value'>` , `<style>#pay { display:none;}  body[data-mode='2'] #pay {display: block;}`

Comment: is there a way to do this without the css? how would i take that logic in css and convert it over to say...javascript?

Comment: i guess you can do something like `<select id="gasGrade" onchange='pay.hidden=value!=2;'>`

Comment: I've tried adding that onchange and it doesn't seem to work. The pay form still exists when I select. Maybe I am missing something? Thank you for the help nonetheless

Comment: You should use either style="display:none" or style="visibility:hidden" to make the form (div) invisible.